# Use Google Drive APIs for android application

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to integrate Google Drive on an Android application.

It looks like it's possible to integrate Google Drive using Google Drive APIs and Google Document List APIs.

Is there any issue to integrated Google Drive, like guidelines or rules?

I downloaded assets of Google Drive icons from Branding Guide Line. Is it OK to use any icons from them?

Is there any guide lines to integrate Google Drive on android application?

I checked the developer documents for Google Drive. It described them for Chrome Web Applications. I couldn't find any documents regarding Android applications. When will documents and guidelines for Android application be released?

I have some questions concerning Google Drive policy. Where can I get these policy questions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10330497/1075066

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306456/android-api-for-google-drive too

Comment: What are your policy questions?

Answer (score 0):

Most of our branding guidelines ar described in [this document](https://developers.google.com/drive/branding) as long as you follow them you should be fine using the assets and the Drive brand.

For your policy questions simply ask them here. If they have legal implication please send an email to legal@google.com, you may also try policy@google.com