# use AuthToken from AccountManager for Google Client API requests

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-api-client, auth-token

I want access the Google Drive account from a user. I get a token from the AccountManager on Android.

I added the Client Library and Drive Library from Google to my project and want to send requests with the received token to the Google service.
How can I do this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306456/android-api-for-google-drive