# Access Google Drive from a desktop application

Tags: google-drive-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android API for Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306456/android-api-for-google-drive)

I want to synchronize a single small xml file between Android application and separate standalone Java-based desktop application. First, a user pushes a button in the Android application and the xml file is stored somewhere in the cloud. Next, the user launches standalone desktop application and gets the xml file from the cloud.

I wanted to use Google Drive for this purpose. However, I am confused about the following from Google Drive help pages:

> Warning: Authorization alone is not sufficient to give your app access
>   to users' files — app installation is also required. Apps will not
>   have any API access to files unless users have first installed the app
>   in Chrome Web Store.

Is there a way to directly grab/write a file from/to Google Drive having the credentials? Or at least a way with least problems for the end user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10306505/1106381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, we realize this isn't feasible with the Drive API, as you'd need a token created for a client ID that had been installed from the Chrome Web Store.  We are planning a fix for this, but don't have anything immediately.  In the immediate term, you should use the Documents List API.