# Google Drive API not returning subfolders for files.list method when using service account for authorization

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a node api running for which it isn't practical to use OAuth for the authentication process, from the google docs this seems to be a good use case for a service account.  The strange thing is that the same code **will** include subdirectories on a files.list() method when using OAuth, but it **won't** when using the service account.  I've verified that the share permissions on the g-drive parent folder and the subdirectory both include editor access for the email assigned by google to the service account.

And still more weirdness - if I leave off the q property when calling files.list when using a service account, all files (including those in the trash) are returned, but still not subdirectories.  From [Google's API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files), if the q property is set to "trashed=false", then files that are in the trash shouldn't be returned, but they are. I'm thinking the issue has to do with the value of the q parameter, because leaving it blank returns everything (regardless of if files were created by the service account), but once values are specified for the q property as per the documentation and the commented out values in the code below, unexpected results are received.

The closest SO post I could find that was similar to my question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934525/unable-to-retrieve-google-drive-files-and-folders-using-new-drive-api/10989624#10989624), but I don't think it's the same thing.  Here's the code I used, and about half way down are the commented out different experiments I tried with the query parameter:

```
const authenticateGdrive = async () => {
  const serviceAccountKey = await readFile(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH, 'utf8');
  const credentials = JSON.parse(serviceAccountKey);

  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    credentials,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'],
  });

  return google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
};

export const list = async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const drive = await authenticateGdrive();
    // problems observed when using a service account for authentication:
    // q: `'${req.body.folderId}' in parents` does not return any subfolder
    // q: 'trashed=false', // pulls in trash anyway, but no q parameter does pull in trash
    // q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", // doesn't retrieve any folders
    const response = await drive.files.list({
      q: `'${req.body.folderId}' in parents`,
      fields: 'files(id, name, mimeType)',
    });

    const files = response.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
      res.status(200).send(files);
    } else {
      res.status(500).send({message: "No files retrieved"});
    };
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({message: error.message});
  };
};
```

The goal is retrieve an array of objects for non-trashed items from the top level folder for which the service account has permissions, including subdirectories, regardless of who the creator is.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Owww - oh my gosh - of course after clicking "Submit" the light bulb came on - the solution was to set the scope to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`