# Android Google Drive integration

Tags: android

I need to upload an file from android device SDCARD onto google cloud, I google long time on internet,but I couldn't found correct version of Api to achieve file share over cloud. Help me with sample code to login and share files over cloud with right api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330053/google-drive-docs-api-for-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no experience of this, but there does seem to be some documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/get-started
Have you already looked through this?

EDIT: That appears to be for Chrome apps. There is a similar question here: [Android API for Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306456/android-api-for-google-drive)

It looks like the short answer is the solution is a long one (people have mentioned having to do it manually :( )