# Access to Google Drive from self implemented Android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My Problem is, that **I want to use any SDK or API to access my google drive from my android phone without using an existing google drive app on my android phone.**

I read the instructions on this side: [google drive sdk](https://developers.google.com/drive/)
The code examples does only work for desktop applications and the "integrate with Android" topic on the side does not provide any example how I can access my google drive from my android application.

I already read [android-api-for-google-drive here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306456/android-api-for-google-drive) but this leads only to more links and how-to's which are far to complicated and fuzzy.

Has anyone experience with connecting to google-drive from an android application and could help with any example code or "clean-and-short-explained" tutorial?

Comment: **"...the "integrate with Android" topic on the side does not provide any example how I can access my google drive from my android application."** - Urrrm, it actually goes quite a long way to explaining it with example manifest and `Activity`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: The example code in the "integrate with Android" article is for the use case that I choose a file in my android device and then the user has the choice to select the Activity to .I want to send a file from my app to the google drive directly, so I can for example send an image, which I have drawn in my app to my google drive account

Comment: See the `Files.insert` API. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, just after you asked this question, Google released their Play Services ([see this link](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/)), which makes it a heck of a lot easier to access files using the Drive SDK & Drive API.  Please see my post on Google Plus that gives a step-by-step walkthrough and code example on how to integrate an Android app with Google Drive documents:  https://plus.google.com/u/0/114042449736049687152/posts/CD3L8zcJg5Z

In the tutorial, I reference a particular Google IO 2012 talk (slides at https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1LrEKp2PqESsES3upS1xsSARz35KS-9QHnYFTKvS2yzM/preview#slide=id.p19), but please read my G+ post because I go through the various flaws, pitfalls, and omitted details from this presentation.

Before you start coding anything, get yourself signed up for the Google APIs ([see this link](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)), get into the API Console, and turn on both the Google Drive API and Drive SDK.

Good luck & have fun!