# Incorporate Google Drive solution in existing Android app project?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have an existing Android app project which has been already published on the Google Play, and now I would like to incorporate in my app the possibility to use the Google Drive possibilities in order to download *.jpg files directly to the sd card when the app is opened or load for the first time. Like this I liberate the internal memories of the phones where this app is installed (All the images are stored in the resources of the app actually which is >~ 20MB). I have read a lot of forums concerning the Google Drive SDK or API subjects and I can say that I'm a little bit lost on the manner to manage it for my present app. Some ideas or suggestions would be very very very appreciated.

Thank you very much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this question for the basics on how to integrate your Android app with Google Drive SDK: [Access to Google Drive from self implemented Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556687/access-to-google-drive-from-self-implemented-android-application/12888877#12888877)

In it, I reference a good Google+ tutorial on how to get started, and it's easy enough to take the concepts and apply them to an existing app.  (That's how I did it too.)  Before you get started, sign up for the Google APIs (https://code.google.com/apis/console/), get into the API Console, and turn on both the Google Drive API and Drive SDK.  This'll make coding go a lot smoother.  Let me know if you have any problems.

One addendum for your specific case relating to *.jpg files is you could set a MIME type for fetching strictly the pictures.  It'd go something like this:

```
    request = service.files().list(); // .setQ("mimeType=\"text/plain\"");
```

Unfortunately setQ is commented out because it would fail to return any results when I used it.  However, you may have better luck with the `image/jpeg` MIME type.

Comment: Okay perfect), thank you very much for your reply. It's a very good point from what I will begin for it. Thank you again).